# Origin of the eq. 5.141 in the Di francesco's book conformal field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Recently I am reading Philippe Francesco's Book: *Conformal Field Theory*. Actually, I am having problems in understanding the origin of the initial part of the following equation:

> $$\left\langle T^{00}\right\rangle =\left\langle T_{zz}\right\rangle +\left\langle T_{\overline{z}\overline{z}}\right\rangle .\tag{5.141} $$

I would also like to know which contravariant metric is necessary to be used in this special case.

I will be very grateful for your great help.

Comment: This is a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Hi @Prahar, I am sure you are right. But probably I am doing some mistake and I can't reach to this equation. Could you give me some clues, please?.

Answer (score 1):

The complex coordinates are defined by:
$$
\partial_z=\frac {1}{2}(\partial_0-i\partial_1)\,,\,\,\,\,\,\, \partial_{\bar {z}}=\frac {1}{2}(\partial_0+i\partial_1).
$$
$$
dz=dz^0+idz^1\,,\,\,\,\,\,\, d\bar{z}=dz^0-idz^1
$$
A good way to see how tensors transforms under change of coordinates is by the identification:
$$
T^{ab}=T^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\beta}
$$
$$
T_{ab}=T_{\alpha\beta}dz^{\alpha}dz^{\beta}
$$
Then
$$
T_{00}dz^0dz^0+T_{01}dz^0dz^1+T^{10}dz^1dz^0+T^{11}dz^1dz^1=\\=T_{00}dz^0dz^0+...+T^{11}dz^1dz^1=T_{00}(dz^0dz^0-dz^1dz^1)+...=\\=\frac{1}{2}T_{00}(dzdz+d\bar {z}d\bar {z})+...\,\,\,\,\,
$$
In the second line we use the fact that the energy-momentum tensor is traceless. In the third line we use the fact that symmetrical combination of the product of $dzdz$ and $d\bar{z}d\bar{z}$ gives the difference between $dz^0dz^0$ and $dz^1dz^1$.

The tensor in $z$-coordinates, because the traceless condition, have $T_{z\bar{z}}=T_{\bar{z}z}=0$, and

$$
T_{ab}=T_{zz}dzdz+T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}d\bar{z}d\bar{z}=\\=\frac{(T_{zz}+T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}})}{2}(dzdz+d\bar{z}d\bar{z})+\frac{(T_{zz}-T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}})}{2}(dzdz-d\bar{z}d\bar{z})
$$
Because $(dzdz-d\bar{z}d\bar{z})$ and $(dzdz+d\bar{z}d\bar{z})$ are linear independent derivatives, and $T_{00}=T^{00}$ then:
$$
T^{00}=T_{zz}+T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}
$$

To calculate the metric tensor do the same thing. Express the tensor in terms of linear combination of partial derivatives or differentials and express the old derivatives  and differentials in terms of the new ones.

Comment: hi, @Nogueira thanks for your quick response, I agree with your deduction and I understand that going from $\left(z^{0},\;z^{1}\right)\longrightarrow\left(z,\;\overline{z}\right)$, the metric tensor should transform like

$g^{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 2\\2 & 0\end{array}\right)$

and also understand that $T^{00}=g^{0\mu}g^{0\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=T_{00}$.

Comment: But all my confusion is where in all this deduction enter the transformation $w=\frac{L}{2\pi}\ln\left(z\right)$ (E.q 5.137) , should not we transform the metric tensor after this transformation? And use it, instead of  $g^{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: @Diego, I apologize for the delay. Conformal transformation is composed of two parts: a diff transformation that changes the metric just by a conformal factor, followed by a Weyl transformation that restore the metric to it's original form. So, the metric that you need to use is still the flat one.